# Visual Studio Code: how to run Python file with Ctrl + Alt + N, but it should save changes first

Tags: visual-studio-code, save

I migrated from [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to Visual Studio Code, I noted that my Python file is not saved automatically when I launch a *Run Code* command.

Currently, I need to run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (save) before I run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (run).

Is there a way to save it by default when running with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>?

My launch.json has the following:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+n",            "command": "code-runner.run" },
```

Edit: to run it I do: ctrl-s and then ctrl-alt-b. I wish to do only ctrl-alt-b

Comment: Re *"lunch.json"*: Not *"launch.json"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen LOL. yes. launch.json (honest mistake)